# qgis2leaf plugin & data defined properties style

Tags: qgis, qgis2leaf

I exported a map with data defined properties style from qgis2leaf, but it doesn't appear like the following map. Only dots appears on the openlayers map. Is it possible to visualize this kind of syle on the exported map?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The plugin itself cannot recreate the logic that lead to the size of the circles and the number displayed within. The size is probably a result from choosing -advanced->scale in the style tab and then you choosen an attribute from you attribute list that defines the area, right?

check this video where I have nearly the same situation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=euRne8vQpdM

There are plans to enhance the plugin in a more versatile direction but yet it is more used in quick webmap creation and not advanced webmap creation. This will result in some sort of JavaScript coding done by yourself.

If you have some issues with the plugin or some enhancements to describe visit the github page (check plugin details in QGIS) or write to me directly as I am the creator and one of the developers of the plugin.